# Temporarily share/deploy a python (flask) application

Tags: python

### Goal

Temporarily (1 month?) deploy/share a python (flask) web app without expensive/complex hosting.

#### More info

I've developed a basic mobile web app for the non-profit I work for. It's written in python and uses flask as its framework. I'd like to share this with other employees and beta testers (<25 people).
Ideally, I could get some sort of simple hosting space/service and push regular updates to it while we test and iterate on this app. Think something along the lines of dropbox, which of course would not work for this purpose. We do have a website, and hosting services for it, but I'm concerned about using this resource as our website is mission critical and this app is very much pre-alpha at this point.

#### Options I've researched / considered

- Self host from local machine/network (slow, unreliable)
- Purchase hosting space (with limited non-profit resources, I'm concerned this is overkill)
- Using our current web server / hosting (not appropriate for testing)

Thanks very much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

One word: [Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you consider complex:

- If you are comfortable with pip requirement files you could try [Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python)
- If you are comfortable with the [Apps Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) you could deploy there.
- Alternately, you could put it on a really inexpensive host like [NearlyFreeSpeech](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/) and run it over CGI (slow) to demo the functionality.